# List files in a remote folder given the URL

Tags: list

I have a questions, and I would love you to try to answer it.
Is it possible to get the list of files from a remote folder in java, knowing just the URL???
 for example:

http://localhost/img get all the images names in this directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are talking about a remote folder, it depends on how you are accessing it.

If it is via a network share, such as \localhost\mypath AND you have access to browse the files, you will be able to do so, just like you would with a local directory.

However, if you are trying to browse a directory on a web server, the web server would have to give you directory browsing ability for you to work with it.